# supervisor does not start process (django server with waitress) as user

Tags: django, supervisord, waitress

I have added the `username=myname` in the supervisor config files.

Then I executed:

```
sudo supervisorctl reread all
sudo supervisorctl reload all
sudo supervisorctl restart all
```

And then I killed all the running processes to make sure they are restarted with the new config. However, one of my processes, a django server, keeps starting as root. Why is it not starting under the respective username?

```
ps aux | grep server.py

> root      4286 19.2  0.5 1336924 180920 ?      Sl   17:22   0:02 python server.py
```

server.py:

```
from waitress import serve

from omics_server.wsgi import application

if __name__ == '__main__':
    serve(application, port='8123',
          url_scheme='https', threads=12,
          max_request_body_size=20*1073741824)
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding `user=myname` fixed this, but lead to problems in other config files.

E.g. apparently for the celery process `username=myname` is sufficient and `user=myname` will not allow celery to start. So, for the `server.py` the supervisor config file has to contain `user=myname` rather than `username=myname`.